# Error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null in phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Here is my javascript file below and i am getting the error  "Error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null" . What changes should i make so that it works fine. Thanks in advance. Please help.

```
var scanCode = function() {
window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
    function(result) {

    alert("Scanned Code: " + result.text 
            + ". Format: " + result.format
            + ". Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
            document.getElementById("d").innerHTML="result.text";
            window.location.href = 'page5.html';

}, function(error) {
    alert("Scan failed: " + error);
});
}
```

I am getting the error as:

```
06-24 11:55:08.130: W/FlashlightManager(7817):  at   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-24 11:55:08.130: W/FlashlightManager(7817):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-24 11:55:08.130: W/FlashlightManager(7817):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-24 11:55:08.130: W/FlashlightManager(7817):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-24 11:55:08.540: D/OpenGLRenderer(7817): Flushing caches (mode 0)
06-24 11:55:08.870: D/OpenGLRenderer(7817): Flushing caches (mode 0)
06-24 11:55:14.920: D/PhoneGapLog(7817): Error in success callback: BarcodeScanner2 = TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
06-24 11:55:14.920: D/PhoneGapLog(7817): file:///android_asset/www/phonegap-1.4.1.js: Line 692 : Error in success callback: BarcodeScanner2 = TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
06-24 11:55:14.930: I/Web Console(7817): Error in success callback: BarcodeScanner2 = TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at file:///android_asset/www/phonegap-1.4.1.js:692
```

here is the HTML code where i am calling the above js function

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no,   width=device-width">
     <title>Bar Code Scanner</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">

  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body id="stage" class="theme">
   <h1>Barcode Scanner and Encoder</h1>
   <h2>PhoneGap Barcode Scanner Plugin</h2>

    <a href="#" class="btn" onclick="scanCode();">Scan Code</a>


 </body>
 </html>
```

and here is another html file where i need to print the result.

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
       <p id="d"></p>
       </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: The error message is telling you the element with an id of `d` doesn't exist.

Comment: So how should i define it? I am a beginner. I dont really know.Plz help

Comment: You add an element to your html page. Something like `<div id="d"></div>`.

Comment: I have added that element but still i am getting the error

Comment: Try moving your script calls to just before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: I tried that as well but still i am getting the same error.

Comment: Post your HTML to http://jsfiddle.net/ and share the link.

Comment: Yes, first of all please tell us which framework version (`phonegap --v`) you use, which plugins you have installed (`phonegap plugins`), which os you are working on (`android`, `iOS`, `bb`, `windows`,...). Then provide a jsfiddle.net for us with the complete code. Are you using `jQuery` or any other javascript library, what is your intent to do with your code? You have to provide a little more information to us, otherwise we cannot help you there!

Comment: I am using phonegap-1.4.1 and I have installed a barcode scanner plugin for android. I am using  jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ::

Page1.html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>

  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no,   width=device-width">
      <title>Bar Code Scanner</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">

      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body id="stage" class="theme">
      <h1>Barcode Scanner and Encoder</h1>
      <h2>PhoneGap Barcode Scanner Plugin</h2>

      <a href="#" class="btn" onclick="scanCode();">Scan Code</a>


  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var scanCode = function () {
          window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
              function (result) {

                  alert("Scanned Code: " + result.text + ". Format: " + result.format + ". Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
                  localStorage.setItem("myvalue", result.text);
                  window.location.href = 'page2.html';

              }, function (error) {
                  alert("Scan failed: " + error);
              });
      }
  </script>

  </html>
```

Page2.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
      <title>Checkd Control</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
      <p id="d"></p>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      var barcodeVal = localStorage.getItem("myvalue");
      document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = barcodeVal;
  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: When I run the following code, I get the error "scanCode is undefined".

Comment: Sorry I didnt get you. I have tried your answer but its unable to detect the function scanCode().

Comment: edit your question, paste your full code of js or html